# Android. Узнать дату последнего запуска приложения по его Bundle ID

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как мне узнать дату последнего запуска (и его длительность) приложения по его BundleID? Например, я хочу узнать, когда последний раз запускалось приложение `com.vkontakte.android`

Я нашел [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager?hl=ru) , но не уверен, в правильную ли сторону я копаю

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825854/how-to-get-the-time-spent-on-an-application-in-android-programmatically

Comment: [Похожий вопрос а англоязычной компании](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362574/how-do-i-know-when-any-of-installed-app-was-last-used-programmatically)